# Drawing very long legend at the bottom of scatterplot3d

Tags: r, plot, legend, scatter-plot, scatterplot3d

How I can put a very long legend at the bottom of the scatterplot3d plot properly? I tried to use layout, oma, mar, but I couldn't figure it out. What I want to have is having the plot at the top and putting the legend at the bottom. I can not proceed further. I really need help :(

Here is the code I tried so far:

```
library("scatterplot3d")


mean_E = c(2.5459233083,-1.75924812,-1.48706767,-1.70857143,-1.7201293233,2.1565954887,-1.3398496,3.353383,-0.96511278,2.81007519,0.8252120301,0.7203008,-1.2539834586,-1.5503759,0.67669,-0.0421053)
mean_P = c(1.02256,-1.744361,-1.56391,0.390977,-0.9819549,1.76015038,-1.962406,2.6294015038,0.526316,2.9744361,0.9172932,0.6315789,-0.6210526,0.93985,1.4208105263,0.406015)
mean_A = c(0.09023,-0.5714,-0.6165414,-0.428571,0.225564,0.80766917,-0.64180451,1.6967218045,-0.030075,2.6631579,0.5714286,0.1609023,-0.7487218,0.3619112782,1.7578947,0.3729323)
statementNameList = c("Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence 1",
"Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence 2",
"Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence 3",
"Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence 4",
"Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence 5",
"Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence 6",
"Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence 7",
"Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence 8",
"Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence 9",
"Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence 10",
"Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence 11",
"Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence 12",
"Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence 13",
"Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence 14",
"Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence 15",
"Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence 16")

mean_df <- data.frame("E"=mean_E,"P"=mean_P,"A"=mean_A,"Sentence"=statementNameList)

expressions <- data.frame("E"=c(-1.569,1.4796,-2.3793,3.4469,-2.4077, 2.8125,-2.5706,  3.0389,-2.09,-2.2676, -2.0267),
                          "P"=c(-1.1345,1.3151,-1.3414,2.9125,-0.7577, 2.2475,0.2676, 1.8417,-0.7833, -0.3514, 1.0667 ),
                          "A"=c(-2.0621,2.3139,-1.8759,0.2438,-0.6808, 2.16,0.4265, -2.7889,-2.19,0.7243,1.7967),
                          "Emotion"= c("Tired", "Surprised", "Sad", "Happy", "Fearful", "Excited", "Disgusted", "Calm", "Bored", "Annoyed", "Angry") )


title="EPA Ratings"
xlabel = "Evaluation (E)"
ylabel = "Potency (P)"
zlabel = "Activitiy (A)"
angle = -70


plot<-scatterplot3d(expressions$E ,expressions$P,expressions$A, main=title,
                    xlab=xlabel, ylab=ylabel, zlab=zlabel, pch = "", grid=TRUE, box=TRUE,
                    angle = angle)
plot$points3d(expressions$E ,expressions$P,expressions$A, pch = 5, col="red")

color_palette = grDevices::colors()[grep('gr(a|e)y', grDevices::colors(), invert = T)]
# select different color for each sentence
colors =sample(color_palette, 16)
plot$points3d(mean_df$E ,mean_df$P,mean_df$A, pch = 16, col=colors, cex=2)

legend(3,-3, legend = statementNameList,col = colors, pch = 16, inset = -0.5, cex = 0.7,
        bty = "n",xpd = TRUE)

text(plot$xyz.convert(expressions$E ,expressions$P,expressions$A-0.2), labels = expressions$Emotion, col = "darkblue", cex=0.6)
```

Here is the current output I have:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try below code.
I found that in this link.
http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/scatterplot3d-3d-graphics-r-software-and-data-visualization

## Custom shapes/colors

```
s3d <- scatterplot3d(iris[,1:3], pch = shapes, color=colors)
legend("bottom", legend = levels(iris$Species),
      col =  c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9"), 
      pch = c(16, 17, 18), 
      inset = -0.25, xpd = TRUE, horiz = TRUE)
```

Comment: The problem is my legend is too big that's why this doesn't work, but anyways thanks for the help :)

Comment: I understand the problem, could you share when you solve this, please ? :)

Comment: Yes, sure, but unfortunately I haven't figured it out yet, so for now, I am printing plot on one figure and legend on another figure and then I combined them together to have a one image :)